# setting image in drawer using Picasso

Tags: android

i have this code in my **Mainactivity.java**
but when ever i run it my app crashes

```
     drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
     NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
     navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
     headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
     ImageView user_pic= (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon_user_pic);


        String url_for_image ="http://"+AppConfig.url+"/testing/"+image_src;

   Picasso.get().load(url_for_image).into(user_pic);
```

Comment: Can you please add the crash error?

Comment: never mind that code works the error was some where else